# CefSharp.WinForms won't load pages?

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Hello i am trying to load pages on my panel in win Forms but it won't render it?
here is my code:

```
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = null;
    public ChromiumWebBrowser myBrowser;
    private string _username;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        // in order to find vehicle location we must use geocoordinate from System.Device.Location
        watcher.StatusChanged += Watcher_StatusChanged;
        watcher.Start();

        // to use diffrent webbrowser control first we must initialize cef.dll controls 
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        myBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
        this.Controls.Add(myBrowser);
        //webPanel.Controls.Add(myBrowser);
        myBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;          
    }
```

Comment: Firstly read the release notes and check if your experiencing a known issue https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases

Comment: This code runs on another pc, but not on the one i currently use. i made all necessary changes for this pc but still won't run @amitland

Comment: Did you read the release notes? If your running on `x64`, then switch to `x86`

Comment: Thank you man it worked.  @amitland